# Python-Django - Como fazer template mostrar apenas items associados ao usuário logado

Tags: python, django, auth

Tenho um pequeno projeto que é uma "to-do list", ou lista de tarefas, feita em Python-Django e vou implementar um sistema de login como já fiz com outros projetos. Porém, dessa vez queria que mostrasse apenas as listas relacionadas aquele usuário logado, como deveria fazer ? Adicionar algo nas views ?

Comment: Estude sobre `request.user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para um usuário poder ver apenas seus itens, é preciso que estes itens estejam marcados com o usuário que é de fato dono dele.

Por isso, seu model de `ToDo` deve conter também um campo que seja chave estrangeira da tabela de usuários do Django.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL contém o nome da tabela que o Django utiliza para guardar os usuários.

Dessa forma, na hora de salvar um ToDo na base, você deve indicar qual é o usuário que é dono deste item. O usuário logado encontra-se dentro do objeto `request`, recebido como parâmetro na view:

```
def salvarItem(request):
    item.usuario = request.user
    item.save()
```

E, por fim, na hora de listar os itens apenas do usuário logado, basta filtrar por este campo:

```
def listarItems(request):
   itens = Item.objects.filter(usuario=request.user)
   return render('tela.html', { 'itens': itens})
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mano, deu certo